# Find the area enclosed by the x = t^2 − 2t, y = √ t and the y axis

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, parametric-functions

How do I find the area for these parametric equations :
x=t^2-2t
y=sqrt(t)
and y axis

Please help[image]

Comment: Welcome to the Mathematica Stack Exchange. This reads like a homework question. More importantly, you have not indicated if it is a math question or a Mathematica question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this not only reads like a homework question but also shows no effort on formatting the question properly (image dump, no latex, no code), no effort articulating what is the problem the OP is facing.  It is not even clear if the question is about Wolfram Language programming.

Comment: The OP (@KurooMikey) is welcome to [edit] their question to improve it and stop or revert the closing procedure. While I appreciate the kindness of the people providing excellent answers to bad questions, I do question the strategy of humoring bad questions. By doing that, are we improving or spoiling the site? We could discuss that in the [chat] or in [meta].

Answer (score 2):

If it's a question concerning  Mathematica try `ParametricRegion` (see @
cvgmt' comment )

**modified**

```
reg = ParametricRegion[{{x, Sqrt[t]}, -2 t + t^2 <= x <= 0}, {x, t}]


Region[reg, Axes -> True]
```

[image]

```
Area[reg]
(*(8 Sqrt[2])/15==0.754*)
```

Comment: I'm not getting the peak for that region, only if I use RegionPlot instead of Region. Do you know what happens, @Ulrich?

Comment: @E.Chan-López You didn't see the complete region?  Which is your Mathematica version? (I'm using v12.2)

Comment: No, I didn't see the complete region. My version is 12.3.1

Comment: Perhaps `Region[reg, Axes -> True,PlotRange->All]` ???

Comment: No, it doesn't work with ``PlotRange-> All`` either.

Comment: It only works by manually adjusting ``PlotRange``.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do it the classical way. Unfortunately we have to use Reduce and Solve, since Solve gives a root-expression which gets not integrated by Integrate and is converted wrong with ToRadicals. (t has to be greater zero to get real y)

```
ParametricPlot[{t^2 - 2 t , Sqrt[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

```
eli = Eliminate[{x == t^2 - 2 t , y == Sqrt[t]}, t]

red = Reduce[{eli, x < 0}, y, Reals]

sol = Solve[red && y > 0, y]

(*   {{y -> ConditionalExpression[
     Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 + x]], 
     -1 < x < 0]}, 
      {y -> ConditionalExpression[
     Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 + x]], 
     -1 < x < 0]}}   *)

Plot[Evaluate[y /. sol], {x, -1, 0}]

{int = Integrate[1, {x, -1, 0}, Evaluate[{y, y /. sol} // Flatten]], 
int // N, 
NIntegrate[1, {x, -1, 0}, Evaluate[{y, y /. sol} // Flatten]]}

(*   {(8 Sqrt[2])/15, 0.754247, 0.754247}   *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer a solution that uses simple tools where we can understand what is going on.

First let us look at the curve:

```
x[t_] = t^2 - 2 t;
y[t_] = Sqrt[t];
ParametricPlot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 2}]
```

[image]

This can easily be integrated if we know the y values for a given x. Therefore, we solve:

```
Solve[Eliminate[{y == y[t], x == x[t]}, t], y]
```

[image]

Form this it is obvious that we need the positive values and x runs from -1 to 0. We may therefore Integrate:

```
Integrate[Sqrt[1 + Sqrt[1 + x]] - Sqrt[1 - Sqrt[1 + x]], {x, -1, 0}]
(* (8 Sqrt[2])/15 *)
```